# What is a good feeding schedule for a "creamy" sourdough starter?

Tags: sourdough, sourdough-starter

I was given a sourdough starter from a bakery that was excellently "creamy" and had light fruity notes, as opposed to a highly acidic starter. My understanding is that a creamy starter indicates a high ratio of lactic to acetic acid. I am interested to know

> How is the lactic acid-production effected by a
> feeding schedule? What feeding schedule is optimal for
> achieving/keeping a creamy stater?

[This post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64979/how-to-get-more-lactic-acid-vs-acetic-acid-in-sourdough) suggests that keeping the starter in a warm climate (30-35 Celcius) improves lactic acid production. What about the feeding frequency and starter/flour/water ratio?